# Segmentation fault during array access

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I want to draw 1 integer from [1,10] a large number of times, then check how many times each integer appears. I wrote this code, it is compiling but showing segmentation fault. Can you, please, point out where the problem is?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <array>

int main(){
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 dre(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution <int> di(1,10);
        std::array<int,10> count{0};
        for(int i=0;i<10000;++i)
        {
                int rand=di(dre);
                count[rand]++;
        }
        for (int foo: count){
                count[foo]/=10000;
                std::cout << foo << " " << count[foo] << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: This is a problem that can be easily solved, or at least drastically narrowed down by **debugging**. Please take the time to learn how to use a debugger. It's immensely helpful and will you save you many hours of just staring at your code. I cannot stress enough how important is to able to debug your own code. Learn it sooner rather than later!

Comment: If I use the -std=gnu++11 compiler option no Segfault occurs - which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Thrawn it's clearly not the compiler's fault here.

Comment: @Thrawn as shown in the answers the problem is the out of bounds access. This is Undefined Behavior, which means anything can happen. It can segfault, it can not segfault.

Comment: @bolov Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please point me to some useful resource which is suitable for beginners? Google search shows lot but hard to find one useful for beginners.

Comment: @anotherone I've editted my answer in response to your followup question.

Comment: Please don't edit your question with given solutions below. It completely changes the meaning of your question and makes it unclear. Please roll it back to @Quentin edit.

Comment: @Ron I only mentioned them under Edit head. Is that correct procedure? It seemed to me. Please inform. Thanks.

Comment: If, after people have solved the problem that your question was about, you find a new problem, then post a new question.

Comment: @underscore_d Oh okay about the second question. I get it now. I just posted in the same question as the main source code is here and then followed by 2 corrections made. I thought just another question for the integer division problem will be spamming SO.

Comment: @anotherone what compiler are you using?

Comment: @bolov: I am using g++-7

Comment: @anotherone do you use a IDE (e.g. codeblocks, eclipse, netbeans)?

Comment: @bolov: No. I code from the terminal and use VIM for text editing.

Comment: debuggin in an IDE is much simpler. But if you are familiar with the terminal and VIM then you can do it in GDB too. Search in google for "gdb tutorial", or "gdb getting started"

Comment: @bolov: thanks. I will check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define an array consisting of 10 elements, like you do here:

```
std::array<int,10> count{0};
```

Then the array will have indices 0-9. So `count` will range from `count[0]` to `count[9]`.

However, here:

```
count[rand]++;
```

when `rand` is 10, you're trying to access `count [10]`, which doesn't exist.

To answer the followup question in your edit, you're looping round and creating `10000` random numbers, here:

```
 for(int i=0;i<10000;++i)
 {
     int rand=di(dre);
```

And as you're picking between 10 different numbers, you'd expect the count of each one to be approximately 1000, with a uniform distribution.

However, when you come to print the results, you divide each count by 10000:

```
count[foo]/=10000;
```

So this means it's highly likely that each count is now approx 0.1. As you're storing it in an int, this gets rounded down to zero.

Comment: @Steve Thanks. The problem was I was doing an integer division inside the for loop. That is why I was getting 0. :P

Answer (score 2):

Your uniform distribution should be defined as:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution <int> di(0, 9);
```

because your array elements are indexed from `0` to `9`. As-is your `rand` variable will eventually become greater than `9` at which point you are reading out of bounds thus causing [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Even if `rand` stays within boundaries your range based `for` loop will exhibit UB because `foo` there is the value of the actual array element yet used as an index. Should be passed by reference instead:

```
for (int& foo : count) {
    foo /= 10000;
    std::cout << foo << '\n';
}
```

Also if you are using C++11 then you will need double braces for the [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) initializer here:

```
std::array<int, 10> count{ { 0 } };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was missing the the reference and also doing an integer division inside the for loop that is why I was getting 0 for all. Everything is fixed now.

Comment: For the compiler I was using g++-7 so double braces should not be a problem I think.

Answer (score 2):

You call `count[rand]` where count has 10 items, meaning indices in the range of 0..9 but rand is in the range of 1..10 so every once in a while it will call `count[10]` which causes your seg fault.

Make the distribution use [0..9] instead: `std::uniform_int_distribution <int> di(0,9);`

Answer (score 2):

With `for (int foo: count)`, `foo` is equal to each element in `count` in turn. You need to use `foo` on its own in the loop instead of `count[foo]`, or use an explicit `for` loop if you need the index.

Additionally, `std::uniform_int_distribution` is bounds-inclusive, so you need to initialize it with `0, 9` instead of `1, 10` to index into your ten-elements `count`.

Comment: I have changed the distribution. But I could not understand your comment about the for loop. I changed it a bit, can you kindly see my comment and explain your correction a bit?